# How to load two dll from embedded resourses?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I have two dlls (`xNet.dll` and `ag.dll`), which I want to use in my project.

I add them to resourses, stated that build action is Embedded Resource.
Next I have such code to load the first dll:

```
public Form1()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += AssemblyResolve;
    InitializeComponent();
}

private static Assembly AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    string assemblyName = args.Name.Split(',')[0];

    using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Yandex.dll.xNet.dll"))
    {
        if (stream == null)
            return null;

        byte[] rawAssembly = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(rawAssembly, 0, (int)stream.Length);
        return Assembly.Load(rawAssembly);
    }
}
```

How to load the second dll?

Comment: why can't you just add them as a reference?

Answer (score -1):

Is

```
using xNet;
using ag;
```

too hard?